# How to get random id's

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I would like to have long random numbers as primary key in my database. I am using mysql and doctrine2.

How do I do this the clever way? Do I create a mysql stored function or should I make a Model function?

I thought mysql would be better because the id need to be unique so working closer to the database should be better. What do you think?

Comment: Have you considered using GUIDs?

Comment: Consider using regular auto_incrementing IDs, then use some padding/salting and `aes_encrypt()` in mysql to generate random-LOOKING keys. The aes version will look like garbage, but can be easily turned back into the original simple numeric key, if need be.

Comment: not sure what THE answer to my question is so i am just spreading out the points. You where all helpfull. Looks like my question wasn't, mh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [UUID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html).

Comment: UUID is a nice idea but I don't like how they look like ;) I think i go with Marc B suggestion to generate the public ID seperatly with a hash function. Still, UUID() could be usefull there. Somethink like sha1(UUID() + primary_id)

Comment: Does mySQL store UUIDs internally as a string, or as a Byte[16]?  Just curious as I use UUIDs quite a bit, but I'm a Postgres guy..

Answer (score 1):

I am not a mysql user but it intrigues me why you would want to add the stress of LONG numbers.

I searched around and found this as the unique id field in a mysql database:

for a new table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
   id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
)
```

for an existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE KEY;
```

Comment: The problem with auto incremented IDs is that you can guess them. That is why big pages like facebook are using random IDs for all objects.